# How do I increase the /proc/pid/cmdline 4096 byte limit?

Tags: linux, process, classpath, pid, limits

For my Java apps with very long classpaths, I cannot see the main class specified near the end of the arg list when using ps.  I think this stems from my Ubuntu system's size limit on /proc/pid/cmdline.  How can I increase this limit?

Comment: Being a non-Java-guy, I wonder how you run that on Windows. XP had a limit of, I think, 2048.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't change this dynamically, the limit is hard-coded in the kernel to PAGE_SIZE in fs/proc/base.c:

```
 274        int res = 0;
 275        unsigned int len;
 276        struct mm_struct *mm = get_task_mm(task);
 277        if (!mm)
 278                goto out;
 279        if (!mm->arg_end)
 280                goto out_mm;    /* Shh! No looking before we're done */
 281
 282        len = mm->arg_end - mm->arg_start;
 283 
 284        if (len > PAGE_SIZE)
 285                len = PAGE_SIZE;
 286 
 287        res = access_process_vm(task, mm->arg_start, buffer, len, 0);
```

Comment: Note that this can be adjusted if you're willing to recompile the kernel to do so (see my comment for a how-to link).

Comment: Anything can be adjusted if you are willing to recompile the kernel but it still can't be changed dynamically.

Comment: Recompiling the kernel feels like moving to a new house because you didn't like the previous one's sofa.

Comment: [This was fixed in June 2015](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c2c0bb44620dece7ec97e28167e32c343da22867) and this answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 28):

For looking at Java processes [jps](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) is very useful.

This will give you the main class and jvm args:

```
jps -vl | grep <pid>
```

Comment: Even worse for me. Truncates quickly

Comment: @HaveAGuess, wfm - it shows the main class, no matter how obscenely long the classpath may be, which is what the OP asked for. (It can also optionally show other arguments.)

Comment: Works for me too, shows all parameters for insanely long (more than 4096 chars) Weblogic command lines (Linux 64bit). Thanks Kevin!

Comment: I am trying `jps` to see full classpath of hadoop java processes... for some reason `jps` won't even show me the classpath!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I needed to add the -m option to see the command line arguments.

Comment: `jps -lvm` even better for me - the `m` is needed to show command-line args (not JVM args) passed to your Java `main` method.

Answer (score 9):

I temporarily get around the 4096 character command line argument limitation of ps (or rather /proc/PID/cmdline) is by using a small script to replace the java command.

During development, I always use an unpacked JDK version from SUN and never use the installed JRE or JDK of the OS no matter if Linux or Windows (eg. download the bin versus the rpm.bin).
I do not recommend changing the script for your default Java installation (e.g. because it might break updates or get overwritten or create problems or ...)

So assuming the java command is in /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java

first move the actual binary away:

```
mv /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java.orig
```

then create a script /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java  like e.g.:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "$@" > /tmp/java.$$.cmdline
   /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java.orig $@
```

and then make the script runnable

```
chmod a+x /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java
```

in case of copy and pasting the above, you should  make sure that there are not extra spaces in  /x/jdks/jdk1.6.0_16_x32/bin/java and #!/bin/bash is the first line

The complete command line ends up in e.g. /tmp/java.26835.cmdline where 26835 is the PID of the shell script.
I think there is also some shell limit on the number of command line arguments, cannot remember but it was possibly 64K characters.

you can change the script to remove the command line text from /tmp/java.PROCESS_ID.cmdline
at the end

After I got the commandline, I always move the script to something like "java.script" and copy  (cp -a) the actual binary java.orig back to java. I only use the script when I hit the 4K limit.

There might be problems with escaped characters and maybe even spaces in paths or such, but it works fine for me.

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to go.  You can also set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable just for that specific command, or split the needed paths between `CLASSPATH` and the command line.

Comment: Great workaround to see the full command line, I've used it for javac too

Comment: If you have access to the actual java executable used (for example in Eclipse), you can skip the moving of the binary and just create the script that prints the commandline (to a file) and then starts the java application. Make sure you place the script in the JDK bin folder.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `jconsole` to get access to the original command line without all the length limits.

Comment: it may work and it increases the length limit, but for really huge command line it doesn't work anymore and gets truncated (just experienced that).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use newer linux distributions, where this limit was removed, for example RHEL 6.8 or later

*"The /proc/pid/cmdline file length limit for the ps command was previously hard-coded in the kernel to 4096 characters. This update makes sure the length of /proc/pid/cmdline is unlimited, which is especially useful for listing processes with long command line arguments. (BZ#1100069)"*

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.8_Release_Notes/new_features_kernel.html

Answer (score 0):

For Java based programs where you are just interested in inspecting the command line args your main class got, you can run:

```
jps -m
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that if you're actually seeing the arguments truncated in /proc/$pid/cmdline then you're actually exceeding the maximum argument length supported by the OS. As far as I can tell, in Linux, the size is limited to the memory page size. See ["ps ww" length restriction](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ps-ww-length-restriction-665255/)  for reference.

The only way to get around that would be to recompile the kernel. If you're interested in going that far to resolve this then you may find this post useful: ["Argument list too long": Beyond Arguments and Limitations](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060)

Additional reference:
[ARG_MAX, maximum length of arguments for a new process](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)

Comment: -1. The first part of your comment is not correct. On my system, `getconf ARG_MAX` says that `ARG_MAX = 2097152` (meaning that my maximum argument length is 2 megabytes). However, `/proc/$pid/cmdline` is truncated to `PAGE_SIZE` which is 4096. Your how-to link does NOT cover this specific situation - I have no idea if changing the relevant bit in `fs/proc/base.c` would cause other problems.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps the 'w' parameter to ps is what you want.  Add two 'w' for greater output.  It tells ps to ignore the line width of the terminal.

Comment: nope, even with ww, it truncates at 4096.  I think ps is reading from /prod/pid/cmdline which is also truncated.

Comment: Just to clarify what @Caskey said with "Add two for greater ouput", that's -w -w (or -ww) for unlimited width in the output.

Comment: @Jay unfortunately it seems it is not unlimited, it is limited to 4096 characters.