# How to get the command line args passed to a running process on unix/linux systems?

Tags: linux, unix, aix, hp-ux, sunos

On SunOS there is `pargs` command that prints the command line arguments passed to the running process.

Is there is any similar command on other Unix environments?

Comment: `tr \\0 ' ' < /proc/<pid>/cmdline`

Answer (score 365, accepted):

There are several options:

```
ps -fp <pid>
cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline | sed -e "s/\x00/ /g"; echo
```

There is more info in `/proc/<pid>` on Linux, just have a look.

On other Unixes things might be different. The `ps` command will work everywhere, the `/proc` stuff is OS specific. For example on AIX there is no `cmdline` in `/proc`.

Comment: on linux, you'll probably need -ww (ie `ps -ww -fp <pid>`) to specify wide output since if there are several commands, they could get cut off.

Comment: For clarification, the file is not /<pid>/ but rather /proc/<pid>

Comment: the `-ww` option allows access to full command-line arguments (as much as is stored by the kernel). See Also: [how solaris and bsd get the untruncated commandline parameters for a process](http://praveen.kumar.in/2010/02/24/getting-untruncated-command-line-options-passed-to-a-solaris-process/) and [ps options](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm)

Comment: ``cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline`` also works on Cygwin, where cmd line arguments are not shown in ``ps`` with any option.

Comment: On Linux, if you only need to get the `args`, the command is `ps -o args -p <pid>` and it will only print the `args` or use -o `cmd` if you only need to see the `cmd`. Trying to read `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` will not always work for unprivilege users. The `ps` utility will work.

Comment: Hint: length of `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` is limited (hard coded to value of PAGE_SIZE kernel parameter), so longer command lines are still shown truncated! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199130/how-do-i-increase-the-proc-pid-cmdline-4096-byte-limit for more info. You can query your kernel setting with `getconf PAGE_SIZE`, it's usually 4096.

Comment: wow that is genius, the `ps -fp` command worked for me on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that the command can be executed with a different name (first arg); in which case you can look at `/proc/<pid>/comm`

Comment: 3c67b1b73daf:~# ps -fp 22823
ps: unrecognized option: p
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-07-17 15:21:40 UTC) multi-call binary.

Answer (score 73):

This will do the trick:

```
xargs -0 < /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

Without the xargs, there will be no spaces between the arguments, because they have been converted to NULs.

Comment: It is stil truncating my output. Any advise?

Comment: Never noticed any truncation - can you give an example?

Comment: This way, you cannot say if it's an inline space or an argument boundary.

Answer (score 28):

### Full commandline

For Linux & Unix System you can use `ps -ef | grep process_name` to get the full command line.

On SunOS systems, if you want to get full command line, you can use

```
/usr/ucb/ps -auxww | grep -i process_name
```

To get the full command line you need to become super user.

### List of arguments

```
pargs -a PROCESS_ID
```

will give a detailed list of arguments passed to a process. It will output the array of arguments in like this:

```
argv[o]: first argument
argv[1]: second..
argv[*]: and so on..
```

I didn't find any similar command for Linux, but I would use the following command to get similar output:

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/<pid>/environ
```

Comment: `ps -ef` is the command I was looking for

Answer (score 25):

On **Linux**

```
cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

outputs the commandline of the process `<pid>` (command including args) each record terminated by a `NUL` character.

A **Bash Shell Example**:

```bash
$ mapfile -d '' args < /proc/$$/cmdline
$ echo "#${#args[@]}:" "${args[@]}"
#1: /bin/bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.17(1)-release
```

Comment: Whitespace isn't removed, it's replaced with NULs.

Comment: @bdonlan Ah, I did not check that. Good catch!

Comment: xargs -0 echo < /proc/<pid>/cmdline . You can also do this with /proc/<pid>/environ too, although you may want to add -n 1 for that.

Comment: On my system there is no /proc filesystem :(
any other solution ?

Comment: Mine is a java process with long long long parameters. It is stil truncating my output. Any advise?

Comment: I've just realized that I voted down this answer by accident. I intended to vote it up. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidRissatoCruz That must be where all those mystery down-votes come from! :-)

Answer (score 19):

You can use `pgrep` with `-f` (full command line) and `-l` (long description):

```
pgrep -l -f PatternOfProcess
```

This method has a crucial difference with any of the other responses: it works on *[CygWin](http://cygwin.com/)*, so you can use it to obtain the full command line of any process running under Windows (execute as [elevated](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824) if you want data about any elevated/admin process). Any other method for doing this on Windows is more awkward ( [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563411/how-to-get-command-line-info-for-a-process-in-powershell-or-c-sharp/17582576#17582576) ).
Furthermore: in my tests, the pgrep way has been **the only system that worked** to obtain the full path for *scripts running inside CygWin's python*.

Comment: This one actually prints the original executable name too: `$ exec -a fakename bash & 
[1] 14102

[1]+  Stopped                 exec -a fakename bash
$ xargs -0 < /proc/14102/cmdline; 
fakename
$ pgrep -l -f fakename;
14102 bash`

Comment: Doesn't work for me using `pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.15` and `3.3.12`. Just prints the pid and prorgam name without arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Another variant of printing `/proc/PID/cmdline` with spaces in Linux is:

```
cat -v /proc/PID/cmdline | sed 's/\^@/\ /g' && echo
```

In this way `cat` prints [NULL characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) as `^@` and then you replace them with a space using `sed`; `echo` prints a newline.

Comment: FYI, you can also use **cat -v /proc/PID/cmdline | sed 's/\^@/\n/g'**. This will replace the null character with a newline character. In doing so, each argument will be printed to it's own line. That way, it's easier to tell one argument from another.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using multiple commands to edit the stream, just use one - tr translates one character to another:

```
tr '\0' ' ' </proc/<pid>/cmdline
```

Answer (score 3):

`ps -eo pid,args` prints the PID and the full command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
ps -o args= -f -p ProcessPid
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the above ways to convert the text, if you simply use 'strings', it will make the output on separate lines by default. With the added benefit that it may also prevent any chars that may scramble your terminal from appearing.

Both output in one command:

strings /proc//cmdline /proc//environ

The real question is... is there a way to see the real command line of a process in Linux that has been altered so that the cmdline contains the altered text instead of the actual command that was run.

Answer (score 1):

try  `ps -n` in a linux terminal. This will show:

1.All processes *RUNNING*, their command line and their *PIDs*

2. The program intiate the processes.

Afterwards you will know which process to kill

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris

```
     ps -eo pid,comm
```

similar can be used on unix like systems.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, with bash, to output as quoted args so you can edit the command and rerun it

```
</proc/"${pid}"/cmdline xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 -n1 \
    bash -c 'printf "%q " "${1}"' /dev/null; echo
```

On Solaris, with bash (tested with 3.2.51(1)-release) and without gnu userland:

```
IFS=$'\002' tmpargs=( $( pargs "${pid}" \
    | /usr/bin/sed -n 's/^argv\[[0-9]\{1,\}\]: //gp' \
    | tr '\n' '\002' ) )
for tmparg in "${tmpargs[@]}"; do
    printf "%q " "$( echo -e "${tmparg}" )"
done; echo
```

Linux bash Example (paste in terminal):

```
{
## setup intial args
argv=( /bin/bash -c '{ /usr/bin/sleep 10; echo; }' /dev/null 'BEGIN {system("sleep 2")}' "this is" \
    "some" "args "$'\n'" that" $'\000' $'\002' "need" "quot"$'\t'"ing" )

## run in background
"${argv[@]}" &

## recover into eval string that assigns it to argv_recovered
eval_me=$(
    printf "argv_recovered=( "
    </proc/"${!}"/cmdline xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 -n1 \
        bash -c 'printf "%q " "${1}"' /dev/null
    printf " )\n"
)

## do eval
eval "${eval_me}"

## verify match
if [ "$( declare -p argv )" == "$( declare -p argv_recovered | sed 's/argv_recovered/argv/' )" ];
then
    echo MATCH
else
    echo NO MATCH
fi
}
```

Output:

```
MATCH
```

Solaris Bash Example:

```
{
## setup intial args
argv=( /bin/bash -c '{ /usr/bin/sleep 10; echo; }' /dev/null 'BEGIN {system("sleep 2")}' "this is" \
    "some" "args "$'\n'" that" $'\000' $'\002' "need" "quot"$'\t'"ing" )

## run in background
"${argv[@]}" &
pargs "${!}"
ps -fp "${!}"

declare -p tmpargs
eval_me=$(
    printf "argv_recovered=( "
    IFS=$'\002' tmpargs=( $( pargs "${!}" \
        | /usr/bin/sed -n 's/^argv\[[0-9]\{1,\}\]: //gp' \
        | tr '\n' '\002' ) )
    for tmparg in "${tmpargs[@]}"; do
        printf "%q " "$( echo -e "${tmparg}" )"
    done; echo
    printf " )\n"
)

## do eval
eval "${eval_me}"


## verify match
if [ "$( declare -p argv )" == "$( declare -p argv_recovered | sed 's/argv_recovered/argv/' )" ];
then
    echo MATCH
else
    echo NO MATCH
fi
}
```

Output:

```
MATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a long-as-possible (not sure what limits there are), similar to Solaris' [pargs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-5202/6je7shk59/index.html), you can use this on Linux & OSX:

```
ps -ww -o pid,command [-p <pid> ... ]
```