# How can I get pid and its executable path information through the file which is executed by this pid?

Tags: file, shell, path, pid, lsof

Based on information for a given file `test.txt`, I hope to get a pid and its executable path for a process that is operating on that file.

For example, if from the command line someone has run this:

```
$ cat test.txt
```

...then I want have something that will give output similar to this:

```
process 1123 bin/cat is using /home/sam/test.txt
```

Comment: I think your question needs tidying up a bit but you are probably looking for something where 'lsof' is involved in the answer. I'll add it as a tag for you ;)

Comment: yes, lsof works. Can I find the information in /proc/ directory?  The information is which pid is executing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is still open, you can use:

```
fuser /home/sam/test.txt
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks! Is there any other methods? If I want to use some basic command, for example ls find grep etc to complete this function. Or can I get the information in /proc/ directory?

Comment: Please see what @DanSut wrote above. `fuser /home/sam/test.txt` will get you a PID. `lsof -p PID` will tell you about the process that has the file open. /proc/PID will have other info, but I think /proc is a Linux-only thing.

Comment: If requirement dose not allow me to use lsof and fuser, how can I do it. Thanks!!!

Comment: yes it is linux system. I cannot get the method, which makes me frustrated.

Comment: `file /proc/*/fd/* | grep /home/sam/test.txt` will get you the PID. `/proc/PID/cmdline` will contain the command. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821837/how-to-get-the-command-line-args-passed-to-a-running-process-on-unix-linux-syste