# RMI disabled, Java still listens on port 1099

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

When I execute `netstat -tupan`, one of the entries is the following:

```
tcp        0      0 :::1099  :::*         LISTEN      8778/java
```

However, I have removed all settings concerning RMI and JMX from the options passed to Java when it starts. My questions are:

1. Is RMI actually still enabled? I can connect to the port using telnet.
2. If not, why does Java still listen on the port?

**Edit:** I blocked the port using netcat: `nc -l 1099`. This prompted an error on the application startup, and it turns out that I have an MBean in the application which was automatically picked up by Spring on startup and registered.

Comment: Did you try to put  your IP/Port in blackhole, just to make sure RMI is culprit

Comment: What's under 8778 PID? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821837/how-to-get-the-command-line-args-passed-to-a-running-process-on-unix-linux-syste

Comment: @jannis: That's my Java application running within Tomcat.

Comment: @ShowStopper: How would that help me identify the cause?

Comment: Having a full command line for you java process (8778) would be very helpful to debug this. Also make sure that you don't have `rmiregistry` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/rmiregistry.html), running as a separate process (throught it will normally display as /rmiregistry in the netstat output). Other options is that you have some JVM agent (jar) attached, which start the registry inside it.

Comment: Maybe you can stop your application, run another application which listened on port 1099. Then start your application again. The `Address already in use` error should display in log file and indicate the class that listened on port 1099.

Comment: @beckyang: Good lateral thinking there. I will definitely try it.

Comment: Could it be that Tomcat itself have opened the port? JMX port often opened for managment purpose. I have seen code where you can register JMX beans on certain port. Port 1099 could also be used for JNDI service, if memory serves me right.

Comment: Check if your application somewhere is creating registry on that port.

Comment: @beckyang: You win, your approach helped me identify the issue pretty fast. Post it as an answer so that I can assign the bounty ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the steps to trace the issue:

1. Stop your application
2. Run another application which listened on port 1099
3. Start your application again
4. `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` exception is thrown by the class that tries to listen on port 1099.

You can work on the issue based on the clue.