# Get command line arguments without arguments in main()

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

One strange thing took my sleep away. .

I have [P7](http://baical.net/p7.html) library. It is library for writing logs.

Library contains few examples.
Example for C++ looks like:

```
int main(int i_iArgC, char* i_pArgV[])
{
   // Some code that don't use i_iArgC or i_pArgV
}
```

But the trick that program handle command line arguments somehow.
I play a little bit to make sure that this main called.
What I do:

1. Build in debug and set breakpoint on `main` (to make sure that exactly
   this `main` is called)
2. Change`main(int i_iArgC, char* i_pArgV[])`   to   `main()` (To make sure that no one use them)

I have no idea how it possible.

Here is minimal steps you can do to look on it by yourself:

1. Download P7 code from [this](http://baical.net/downloads.html) page (link at top left)
2. Unzip archive
3. Run build.sh (It runs few makefiles in some order)
4. Execute `Cpp_Example` from `Binaries` folder
5. Execute again `Cpp_Example /P7.Help` to see that app react to command line arguments.

Comment: I found it! Neat.

Comment: You found where code use `i_iArgC` etc?

Comment: No define (MACRO) or flag to select other program entry point (which then redirect to `main`)?

Comment: No. I don't found such tricks. Build is simple as possible and no way to hide such thing.      But in one of Header files I found `#define P7TRACE_NO_VA_ARG_OPTIMIZATION` and `#include <stdarg.h>`. Maybe they use `stdarg.h` in some way to get arguments directly.

Comment: @isanae exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most systems allow for getting the command line parameters without relying on `main()`. On Windows for example, you can use [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew).

The library has non-portable code to do just that in `Shared/Platforms/*/PProcess.h`. A quick look at `Windows_x86/PProcess.h` shows that it uses `GetCommandLineW()` and the same file in `Linux_x86/` reads [`/proc/self/cmdline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821837).