# Get script name by PID

Tags: python, windows, pid

I have a list of PID and need the Python script names. Is there a way to resolve the PID?

I tried it already with `psutil` and `subprocess`, but I just get 'python.exe' returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the command line args passed to a running process on unix/linux systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821837/how-to-get-the-command-line-args-passed-to-a-running-process-on-unix-linux-syste)

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that you seem to be on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with WMIC:

> wmic process get processid,commandline

or with a WMI query:

> Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = 1"

There is also a python WMI wrapper if you want to do this in python code: https://pypi.org/project/WMI/

Edit:
After some research, I have found out that it is possible to achieve this with `psutils` too. Just invoke `cmdline` on your process instance. -> https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cmdline