# How does JPS tool get the name of the main class or jar it is executing

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I am wondering, how does JPS tool get the name of the main class it is executed within jvm process. It is

```
jps -l
123   package.MainClass
456   /path/example.jar
```

I am talking specifically about Linux (I am not interested in Windows, and I have no Win machine to experiment on).

I could think of 2 ways

1. Connecting to the JVM in question which in turn tells it
2. From `/proc` file system

Regarding the first alternative, is it using local JMX connection? Still, it must go to `/proc` for the pids.

1. There is PID, so it must ask OS anyway
2. `jps` lists also itself

Regarding the second alternative, I feel this could be the correct one, because

1. On the command line, there is either `-jar` or `MainClass`
2. `/proc` knows wery well the PID
3. Before `jps` starts doind something, it has own folder in `/proc`

**But**, I am facing little problem here. When java command is very long (e.g. there is extremely long `-classpath` parameter), the information about the command line does not fit into space reserved for it in `/proc`. My system has 4kB for it, and what I learned elsewhere, this is hardwired in OS code (changing it requires kernel compilation). However, even in this case `jps` is still able to get that main class somewhere. How?

I need to find quicker way to get JVM process than calling `jps`. When system is quite loaded (e.g. when number of JVMs start), `jps` got stuck for several seconds (I have seen it waiting for ~30s).

Comment: The `/proc/___/cmdline` size limit is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199130/how-do-i-increase-the-proc-pid-cmdline-4096-byte-limit

Comment: For those interested in getting what `jps` and also `jstat` provide, but using Python from hsperfdata files: http://blog.martinhynar.cz/2014/08/05/Reading-jvm-information.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jps` scans through `/tmp/hsperfdata_<username>/<pid>` files that contain monitors and counters of running JVMs. The monitor named `sun.rt.javaCommand` contains the string you are looking for.

To find out the format of PerfData file you'll have to look into [JDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/jvmstat/perfdata/monitor).