# How to get the maximum value for ps output in Linux (Ubuntu, RedHat, CentOS...)?

Tags: ubuntu, process, redhat, pid, truncated

I'm looking for a way to report all the command lines associated to all the processes in all Linux: CentOS: Ubuntu, Red Hat, Debian, Cent OS...
And, in case of the best command for it has any limitation (I mean, truncating the command lines), I want to know at what point are they truncated

At this moment I'm using this command
`ps -eo pid,ppid,comm,args > ps.txt`

I read in many places about `getconf PAGE_SIZE`, but it says 4096 and, in the txt file, I can see processes with command lines much longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

According to my investigations, there are 2 possible options:

- truncation at the value of `getconf PAGE_SIZE`, usually 4096
- unlimited characters

The only way to check in what case we are, is from the kernel

- In Cent Os or Red Hat, the truncated is avoided since they released the kernel version 2.6.32-642 (Red Hat 6.8)
  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/6.8_release_notes/new_features_kernel

  > The /proc/pid/cmdline file length limit for the ps command was previously hard-coded in the kernel to 4096 characters. This update makes sure the length of /proc/pid/cmdline is unlimited, which is especially useful for listing processes with long command line arguments.

Here all the versions of Red Hat kernels
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/6.8_release_notes/new_features_kernel

- In Ubuntu, Oracle Linux Server, Debian, SuSE and Fedora, since the kernel version 4.2.
  It can be checked in the source code, as other user said here
  [How do I increase the /proc/pid/cmdline 4096 byte limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199130/how-do-i-increase-the-proc-pid-cmdline-4096-byte-limit)
  In the release 4.2, they started to split the command line in blocks of PAGE_SIZE in order to be able to display the whole command line

The change in the method **proc_pid_cmdline_read** (to display the command lines) can be checked here, throughout the different versions.

Linux Kernel 4.0
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ralf/linux/+/linux-4.0/fs/proc/base.c
Linux Kernel 4.1
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ralf/linux/+/linux-4.1/fs/proc/base.c
Linux kernel 4.2
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ralf/linux/+/linux-4.2/fs/proc/base.c

All the linux kernel vesions releases
https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ralf/linux/+refs

All the Ubuntu versions with its kernels
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions